# DIV CSS Scale transition blurry and shakey

Tags: html, css

No matter what I try and I can't get a nice looking transition of a DIV that I'm scaling up.

https://jsfiddle.net/ugoqrap6/7/

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I've been trying lots of difference suggestions but none of them seem to make a difference.

Comment: What is the resulting effect you are after? just that the image increases in size on hover?

Comment: `image-optimise` code is not helping, remove it.

Comment: @Brad yeah just to increase the size of the DIV

Comment: @Kyle It is a higher res image

Comment: I have removed the image-optimise https://jsfiddle.net/ugoqrap6/8/

Comment: The image is too large

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transform: scale(1.2);`

I have done a simple example here as there is lots of other stuff going on in your code, this should make it easier for future readers

As others have pointed out, be aware of stretching an image.

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a img {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but there image still has a strange effect on it. Also scaling by 1.5 is too big

Comment: Reduced the scale then, use 1.2 or whatever. I think the effect you are describing is not going to go away as its the image being rendered multiple times as its animates. maybe try blurring the image in as it increases to hide this effect. Ill do an example brb

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jquery option, it briefly fades out so you avoid the stretching animation.

```js
$('.thumb').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "scale(1.2)");
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
  });
})

$('.thumb').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "scale(1)");
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li a img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="thumb" src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="thumb" src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="thumb" src="http://aspublic.blob.core.windows.net/drupal-files/bubble_bobble.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it loses the effect some what as this will be in a big grid...